# How to get Eclipse intro to export correctly?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application with an welcome page implementing org.eclipse.ui.intro.config in one of the plugins within a product.  This welcome page works correctly when run from the IDE but fails with a file not found error when running from a PDE export. 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\app\introContent.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

If I copy the introContent.xml to the app directory the error changes to all of the referenced pages.

How can I get an exported RCP app to run the intro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (like most export issues) is to ensure that you have selected the items for export in the build.properties.

Comment: I concur. Check your build.properties and see introcontext.xml is included or not.